# Propagate typescript captured generic type to the class method argument type

Tags: typescript, typescript-generics

Having a problem with captured generic type propagation to a method argument type

```js
class AClass<ExpectedOptions, RealOptions> {
  constructor(public options: RealOptions) {}
  method(options: Omit<ExpectedOptions, keyof RealOptions>) {}
}

interface Options {
  a: string;
  b: string;
}
```

It doesn't work if AClass use directly

```
const aClass = new AClass<Options>({ a: 'value a'}); // should have only 1 type argument 
aClass.method({ }); // this method should be missing b property
```

But It works perfectly with a middle class

```
class A<RealOptions> extends AClass<Options, RealOptions> {
  constructor(options: RealOptions) {
    super(options);
  }
}
const aClass = new A({ a: 'value a'});
aClass.method({ });
```

**UPD**:
There is a workaround by providing an argument type, but I'm looking for a oneliner with the type capturing

```
const options = { a: 'value a'};
const aClass = new AClass<Options, typeof options>(options);
aClass.method({ }); // it requires b
```

Comment: That code doesn't compile for me with Typescript 4.6.2. What version of Typescript are you using and what does your config file look like.

Comment: Right, that is the issue, I've added a working example, but I want to avoid to define a new class

Comment: You can’t just partially apply type functions in TS (just like you can’t partially apply functions in JS).  You could probably refactor to get behavior closer to what you want but I’m not really sure what that behavior is.  What type do you want `aClass` to be?

Comment: you can apply partially function in JS, this pattern even has the name `Currying`

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do doesn't work. If a type has multiple generic type parameters you have to provide enough information to the compiler for it to infer all of their types. In the first case, the compiler has no information that allows it to infer the type of `ExpectedOptions` so it's a compilation error.

However, you don't need to declare a new class, you can just use a type alias

```js
type A<RealOptions> = AClass<Options, RealOptions>
```